# Failing to build bitcoin-core v0.13.1

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, compiling, make

I have done quite a few upgrades in the past and this has never happened before:

```
$ uname -a
Linux back 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ git checkout v0.13.1
$ git fetch --all
$ ./autogen.sh
...
$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/bitcoin/db4/lib/" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/bitcoin/db4/include/"
...
$ make clean  # I have had issues in the past, always solved with clean target
...
$ make
...
AR       leveldb/libmemenv.a
CXXLD    bitcoind
libbitcoin_util.a(libbitcoin_util_a-util.o): In function `GetNumCores()':
/home/me/bitcoin/src/util.cpp:796: undefined reference to `boost::thread::physical_concurrency()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:3336: recipe for target 'bitcoind' failed
make[2]: *** [bitcoind] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/me/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:8357: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:668: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed 
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any suggestion of anything I could try out to resolve this?

**EDIT**: I can't even rebuild `v0.13.0`, so I have most likely messed up my system in relation to `boost`. Looking into that

**EDIT2 (RESOLVED)**: cleaning up the boost install resolves the problem (`make check` passes all tests). Any Bitcoin enthusiast who still doesn't quite know what he is doing (like myself) will easily attempt to install various Bitcoin libraries and utilities (e.g. `libbitcoin` `bx` for C++) with boost dependencies and end up with various bits and pieces of the library everywhere (both `/usr` and `/usr/local` hierarchy as well as boost distribution packages on top of existing stuff in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`). So I removed the distribution packages, cleaned up `/usr/include/boost` and `/usr/lib/libboost_*` (and the equivalent on `/usr/local`), left the gnu folder alone (libreoffice will break otherwise), and installed a clean copy of boost (on `/usr/local` hierarchy). One thing to remember, if anyone tries to experiment by moving around library files, you need to run `ldconfig` to update the cache for the linker I think. Things started to make sense after I did that.

**EDIT3**: for the sake of completeness, if I decide to install boost in the `/usr/` hierarchy rather than `/usr/local/`, then the above build will also fail for some reason. However, replacing the line:

```
$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/bitcoin/db4/lib/" \
              CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/bitcoin/db4/include/"
```

by:

```
$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/bitcoin/db4/lib/ -L/usr/lib" \
              CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/bitcoin/db4/include/ -I/usr/include"
```

leads to a succesful build.

Comment: Try git clean -dfx (this will remove all build results and files not checked in, so you can start fresh). Also, what version of Boost do you have?

Comment: Thank you very much ! I tried that. I retried after reinstalling boost 1.61. Same errors. Will keep looking. Thanks anyway !!